# Which cable internet speed is most appropriate/realistic

Tags: isp

I hope this is an appropriate question to ask. I have tried to do some research on this, but everything I find is incredibly specific and doesn't really answer the questions at a level I understand.

The basis of this question is to help while purchasing internet, so I know what I am looking at.

EDIT: I have tried to edit this question to make it more appropriate for the site. I tried to generalize it to make it less of a service recommendation and therefore helpful to more users.

My basic question is how much of a difference would one see while using the internet at two different speeds: 50 mbps and 100 mbps. Also how much is this affected by streaming video or gaming on multiple devices on the same network. By how much I suppose I mean at what point (how many devices) for each of these speeds would you notice a lag in speed.

I understand that one is "twice as fast" but what does that really mean? How much faster is that? Are we talking seconds or milliseconds to load a website with dynamic content and video? Is this the difference between streaming in HD quality and regular quality or simply in how fast the streaming loads?

The last question I have is how a contention ratio affects internet service. For instance how would I figure out, given a contention ratio and the amount of users in an area, what kind of speed the service is likely to have during peak times?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser! The question you ask is [probably off-topic here](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) as it's about a [service recommendation](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). If you can edit and reword your question, you might get better answers.

Comment: Also, there is something called a [contention ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contention_ratio) that applies to Internet connections. That is what causes the Internet speed to degrade when more people are trying to use the Internet. According to Wikipedia: *The higher the contention ratio, the greater the number of users that may be trying to use the actual bandwidth at any one time and, therefore, the lower the effective bandwidth offered, especially at peak times*. You might need to check your Internet plan and/or contact Cox to find out what yours might be (if it applies to you).

Comment: All things considered, if the price difference is only $10 for twice the bandwidth you might want to consider the 100 Mbps plan.

Comment: [This page](http://www.cox.com/aboutus/policies/oklahomacity/speedsusage.cox) says that the *Premier Package* which is the plan with the 100 Mbps download speed has a monthly limit of upto 300 GB (combined upload & download) so if you exceed that limit, Cox might downgrade your Internet speed.

Comment: Thank you that is all quite helpful. I tried to edit the question to be more suitable for the site. I think I realized that my two main questions were how to understand the likelihood the contention ratio problem will affect me (I clearly need to speak with Cox) and without the contention ratio how noticeable is the difference between speeds likely to be.

Comment: Without contention ratio you'll have twice the bandwidth you would otherwise have with the 50 Mbps plan. This means a download speed of 12.5 MB/s as opposed to 6.25 MB/s. So with the 100 Mbps plan you can download a 700 MB file in 56 seconds as opposed to 112 seconds with the 50 Mbps plan (if you maintain a constant download speed). But that's just the download speeds. Actual page load times depend on a lot of factors (server speed, congestion, latency, etc.). A good way to determine connection quality is to do a [PingTest](http://www.pingtest.net) scan

Comment: Regarding the contention ratio, the higher the ratio the more you'll 'contend' for bandwidth and hence, Internet speed. So if normally your contention ratio is 3:1, you wouldn't have to contend for speed as much as if it were say 20:1 (which may be the case past the 300 GB/month bandwidth cap). You could think of it as sharing a pie between 3 people in the first case and 20 in the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very area specific, as your research already suggested.

What I'd suggest is to go with the 50mbps one and if you noticed too many issues due to your service, then you upgrade. 50 can easily support what you want (although lag is has mostly with your delay and not bandwidth).

The nature of cable service is that it is a shared service so you can get "up to" and hence having a 100mbps when things are congested may not actually help. It is like having a faster car caught in a traffic jam.

There is one other thing to note and that is the upload speed you get. It is typically 50 down and 5 up, vs 100 down and 10 up. 5 up is pretty decent too, unless you have upload intensive things (e.g. bitorrent, P2P sharing, lots of Dropbox and cloud storage stuff - this includes taking video clips that is automatically uploaded to iCloud, Dropbox or Google Drive). In that case, the extra upload speed may actually help.

Finally, make sure that your internal network, mainly your wireless router is in good shape. 50/5 is a pretty decent speed. Use speedtest.net at different times to measure your speed at different times and on different points in your network to get a good sense of how things are going.

Comment: So with the shared service if it is a congested time, does that mean at that time I would basically get the same speed as everyone since everybody is trying to use it at once?

Comment: I think you are right, but typically, it is not that bad. Think about it like your workplace network. If the service you have there is 100mbps all the folks in your office are sharing it. It happens all the time in all the network. Typically, the hubs (the first level you are connected to in Cox network) are engineered to have enough bandwidth to support what is typically needed by the customers they serve (e.g. 1-10 gbps) but it is almost always less than what is the total nominal bandwidth of the subscribers it is serving (potentially 10s of gbps).

Comment: You typically do not notice it since there are other parts of your network which cannot keep up with the speed or the application is not demanding. E.g. watching a 1080p clip on youtube will not need more than 10mbps. A typical wifi router (sub $100) on 2.4 band in a normal house may or may not pass 50mbps mark.

Comment: I see. So it sounds safe to say that in a 1200 sq ft with 2 people using devices each (presumably a phone browsing the internet another device  streaming video) with a fairly new dual band router/modem combo (we have a Netgear N600) we are probably unlikely to the 50mbps mark and therefore not likely to notice a difference unless the network is congested?

Comment: Depends on where you have placed you router and your home decoration, but I think that router is good enough to pass 50mbps on 2.4 band if you are in the same room. 100mbps on 2.4, I would not bet on it. Like I said, use speedtest.net in different places in your apartment to check how thing are going and compare it to the case when you are wired to your router with your laptop.